# I am getting some double database entries from the from my form submission

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an online application That is working but I am getting some double database entries. Not every submission creates a double entry but many are. If anyone sees the reason in my code and can tell me It would be appreciated:

```
<?php
@$upload_Name = $_FILES['Resume']['name'];
@$upload_Size = $_FILES['Resume']['size'];
@$upload_Temp = $_FILES['Resume']['tmp_name'];
@$upload_Mime_Type = $_FILES['Resume']['type'];

function RecursiveMkdir($path)
 {
   if (!file_exists($path)) 
   { 
      RecursiveMkdir(dirname($path));
      mkdir($path, 0777);
    }
}
// Validation
// check only if file
if( $upload_Size > 0)
{

if( $upload_Size == 0)
{
header("Location: error.html");
}
if( $upload_Size >200000)
{
//delete file 
unlink($upload_Temp);
header("Location: error.html");
}
if( $upload_Mime_Type != "application/msword" AND $upload_Mime_Type !=         "application/pdf" AND $upload_Mime_Type != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
{
unlink($upload_Temp);
header("Location: error.html");
}
}//end wrapper of no file
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = “../../XXXX/uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['Resume']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Resume']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['Resume']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "";
}
?><?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
require_once 'Mail.php'; // PEAR Mail package
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

$email_to = “name@yoursite.com”;  //Enter the email you want to send the form     to
$email_subject = "Employment Application";  // You can put whatever subject     here 
$host = "mail.yourdomain.com";  // The name of your mail server. (Commonly     mail.yourdomain.com if your mail is hosted with xxx)
$username = "yoursite.com";  // A valid email address you have setup 
$from_address = "name@yoursite.com";  // If your mail is hosted with Site this     has to match the email address above 
$password = “XXX”;  // Password for the above email address
$reply_to = “XXX@yoursite.com";  //Enter the email you want customers to reply to
$port = "50"; // This is the default port. Try port 50 if this port gives you issues and your mail is hosted with Site

function died($error) {
// your error code can go here 
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you     submitted. "; 
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// Validate expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['Position_Applying']) || !isset($_POST['Position_type']) ||         !isset($_POST['First_name']) || !isset($_POST['Last_name']) ||         !isset($_POST['Street']) || !isset($_POST['City']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}

$hdw_id = $_POST['hdw_id'];
$hdw_Country = $_POST['hdw_Country'];
$hdw_IP = $_POST['hdw_IP'];
$hdw_Referer = $_POST['hdw_Referer'];
$hdw_ServerTime = $_POST['hdw_ServerTime'];
$hdw_Browser = $_POST['hdw_Browser'];
$hdw_UserAgent = $_POST['hdw_UserAgent'];
$Position_Applying = $_POST['Position_Applying'];
$Position_one = $_POST['Position_one'];
$Position_two = $_POST['Position_two'];
$Position_three = $_POST['Position_three'];
$Position_type = $_POST['Position_type'];
$Shift_type = $_POST['Shift_type'];
$First_name =$_POST['First_name'];
$Middle_name = $_POST['Middle_name'];
$Last_name = $_POST['Last_name'];
$Street = $_POST['Street'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
$One_Phone = $_POST['One_Phone'];
$crlf = "n";
 // required 
$error_message = ""; 
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.            <br />';
} 
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$First_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Employment Application Details Below.\n\n";
function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Position Applying: ".clean_string($Position_Applying)."\n";
$email_message .= "Position Type: ".clean_string($Position_type)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "First name: ".clean_string($First_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($Last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$email_message .= "Street: ".clean_string($Street)."\n";
$email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($City)."\n";
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($State)."\n";
$email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($One_Phone)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$email_message .= "Referred By: ".clean_string($Referred_by )."\n";
$email_message .= "Older than 18: ".clean_string($eighteen )."\n";
$email_message .= "US Citizen: ".clean_string($US_citizen)."\n";
$email_message .= "Crime Conviction: ".clean_string($Crime_convict)."\n";
$email_message .= "NYS Professional License:     ".clean_string($NYS_professional_lic)."\n";
$email_message .= "Other License:     ".clean_string($Other_professional_lic)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($Resume,'application/pdf'); 

    // This section creates the email headers
    $auth = array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    $headers = array('From' => $from_address, 'To' => $email_to, 'Subject' =>     $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);

    // This section send the email
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
    $mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $email_message);

    // This section creates the email headers
    $auth = array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    $headers = array('From' => $from_address, 'To' => $email, 'Subject' =>             $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);
// This section send the email
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
    $mail = $smtp->send($email, $headers, $email_message);



if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {?>
<!-- include your own failure message html here -->
  Unfortunately, the message could not be sent at this time. Please try again later.

<!-- Uncomment the line below to see errors with sending the message -->
<!-- <?php echo("<p>". $mail->getMessage()."</p>"); ?> -->

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- include your own success message html here -->


<?php } } ?>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {font-size: 14px}
.style3 {   font-size: 14px;
font-family: Verdana;
}
-->
</style>
<link href=“XXXDatabaseB/js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-image: url(XXXDatabaseB/images/green100px.jpg);
background-color: #FFF09F;
}
.style4 {color: #A20246}
a {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #FFF09F;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style5 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style6 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
-->
</style>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- ImageReady Slices (xxx_square_slice.psd) -->
    <table width="830" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"     bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="Table_01">
    <tr valign="top">
    <td height="258" colspan="2"><?php include 'header.php'; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top">     
    <?php
    $host = “xxxxx.net";
    $username = “xxxxx”;
    $password = “xxxxx”;
       $dbname = “xxxxxx”;

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
$hdw_id = $_POST['hdw_id'];
$hdw_Country = $_POST['hdw_Country'];
$hdw_IP = $_POST['hdw_IP'];
$hdw_Referer = $_POST['hdw_Referer'];
$hdw_Browser = $_POST['hdw_Browser'];
$hdw_UserAgent = $_POST['hdw_UserAgent'];
$Position_Applying = $_POST['Position_Applying'];
$Position_one = $_POST['Position_one'];
$Position_two = $_POST['Position_two'];
$Position_three = $_POST['Position_three'];
$Position_type = $_POST['Position_type'];
$Shift_type = $_POST['Shift_type'];
$First_name =$_POST['First_name'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `new_app`(`hdw_id`, `hdw_Country`, `hdw_IP`, `hdw_Referer`, `hdw_ServerTime`, `hdw_Browser`, `hdw_UserAgent`, `Position_Applying`, `Position_one`, `Position_two`, `Position_three`, `Position_type`, `Shift_type`, `First_name`) 

 VALUES ('$hdw_id', '$hdw_Country', '$hdw_IP', '$hdw_Referer', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$hdw_Browser', '$hdw_UserAgent', '$Position_Applying', '$Position_one', '$Position_two', '$Position_three', '$Position_type', '$Shift_type', '$First_name')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
    <table width="100%" height="508" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="20"     cellspacing="5">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" valign="middle">
            <h2>Thank you for your Application!</h2>
</p>

  </td></tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><?php include 'footer.php'; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of code. Is it all necessary in order to portray your problem and obtain an answer? (Don't remove necessary parts, but do trim if possible)

Comment: just a suggestion you should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me the insert is not executed twice and is no where near a loop of any kind. So it makes me wonder that maybe its user error. I would look at how the file upload section seems to allow the rest of the code to run even if it fails. If it fails the user will change something with the file and resubmit. This happens because you need to `exit;` after your headers.

I also like to end my insert statements with a `LIMIT 1` just because it is limited to one - but I doubt that the problem.

I have made the changes I suggested in the code below:

```
<?php
@$upload_Name = $_FILES['Resume']['name'];
@$upload_Size = $_FILES['Resume']['size'];
@$upload_Temp = $_FILES['Resume']['tmp_name'];
@$upload_Mime_Type = $_FILES['Resume']['type'];

function RecursiveMkdir($path)
 {
   if (!file_exists($path)) 
   { 
      RecursiveMkdir(dirname($path));
      mkdir($path, 0777);
    }
}
// Validation
// check only if file
if( $upload_Size > 0)
{

if( $upload_Size == 0)
{
header("Location: error.html");
exit;
}
if( $upload_Size >200000)
{
//delete file 
unlink($upload_Temp);
header("Location: error.html");
exit;
}
if( $upload_Mime_Type != "application/msword" AND $upload_Mime_Type !=         "application/pdf" AND $upload_Mime_Type != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
{
unlink($upload_Temp);
header("Location: error.html");
exit;
}
}//end wrapper of no file
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = “../../XXXX/uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['Resume']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Resume']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['Resume']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "";
}
?><?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
require_once 'Mail.php'; // PEAR Mail package
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

$email_to = “name@yoursite.com”;  //Enter the email you want to send the form     to
$email_subject = "Employment Application";  // You can put whatever subject     here 
$host = "mail.yourdomain.com";  // The name of your mail server. (Commonly     mail.yourdomain.com if your mail is hosted with xxx)
$username = "yoursite.com";  // A valid email address you have setup 
$from_address = "name@yoursite.com";  // If your mail is hosted with Site this     has to match the email address above 
$password = “XXX”;  // Password for the above email address
$reply_to = “XXX@yoursite.com";  //Enter the email you want customers to reply to
$port = "50"; // This is the default port. Try port 50 if this port gives you issues and your mail is hosted with Site

function died($error) {
// your error code can go here 
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you     submitted. "; 
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />"; 
echo $error."<br /><br />"; 
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// Validate expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['Position_Applying']) || !isset($_POST['Position_type']) ||         !isset($_POST['First_name']) || !isset($_POST['Last_name']) ||         !isset($_POST['Street']) || !isset($_POST['City']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}

$hdw_id = $_POST['hdw_id'];
$hdw_Country = $_POST['hdw_Country'];
$hdw_IP = $_POST['hdw_IP'];
$hdw_Referer = $_POST['hdw_Referer'];
$hdw_ServerTime = $_POST['hdw_ServerTime'];
$hdw_Browser = $_POST['hdw_Browser'];
$hdw_UserAgent = $_POST['hdw_UserAgent'];
$Position_Applying = $_POST['Position_Applying'];
$Position_one = $_POST['Position_one'];
$Position_two = $_POST['Position_two'];
$Position_three = $_POST['Position_three'];
$Position_type = $_POST['Position_type'];
$Shift_type = $_POST['Shift_type'];
$First_name =$_POST['First_name'];
$Middle_name = $_POST['Middle_name'];
$Last_name = $_POST['Last_name'];
$Street = $_POST['Street'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
$One_Phone = $_POST['One_Phone'];
$crlf = "n";
 // required 
$error_message = ""; 
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; 
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.            <br />';
} 
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; 
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$First_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Employment Application Details Below.\n\n";
function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Position Applying: ".clean_string($Position_Applying)."\n";
$email_message .= "Position Type: ".clean_string($Position_type)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n";
$email_message .= "First name: ".clean_string($First_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($Last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$email_message .= "Street: ".clean_string($Street)."\n";
$email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($City)."\n";
$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($State)."\n";
$email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($One_Phone)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$email_message .= "Referred By: ".clean_string($Referred_by )."\n";
$email_message .= "Older than 18: ".clean_string($eighteen )."\n";
$email_message .= "US Citizen: ".clean_string($US_citizen)."\n";
$email_message .= "Crime Conviction: ".clean_string($Crime_convict)."\n";
$email_message .= "NYS Professional License:     ".clean_string($NYS_professional_lic)."\n";
$email_message .= "Other License:     ".clean_string($Other_professional_lic)."\n";
$email_message .= "\n"; 
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($Resume,'application/pdf'); 

    // This section creates the email headers
    $auth = array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    $headers = array('From' => $from_address, 'To' => $email_to, 'Subject' =>     $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);

    // This section send the email
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
    $mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $email_message);

    // This section creates the email headers
    $auth = array('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    $headers = array('From' => $from_address, 'To' => $email, 'Subject' =>             $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to);
// This section send the email
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $auth);
    $mail = $smtp->send($email, $headers, $email_message);



if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {?>
<!-- include your own failure message html here -->
  Unfortunately, the message could not be sent at this time. Please try again later.

<!-- Uncomment the line below to see errors with sending the message -->
<!-- <?php echo("<p>". $mail->getMessage()."</p>"); ?> -->

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- include your own success message html here -->


<?php } } ?>


<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {font-size: 14px}
.style3 {   font-size: 14px;
font-family: Verdana;
}
-->
</style>
<link href=“XXXDatabaseB/js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-image: url(XXXDatabaseB/images/green100px.jpg);
background-color: #FFF09F;
}
.style4 {color: #A20246}
a {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px;
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #FFF09F;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style5 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style6 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
-->
</style>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- ImageReady Slices (xxx_square_slice.psd) -->
    <table width="830" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"     bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="Table_01">
    <tr valign="top">
    <td height="258" colspan="2"><?php include 'header.php'; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" valign="top">     
    <?php
    $host = “xxxxx.net";
    $username = “xxxxx”;
    $password = “xxxxx”;
       $dbname = “xxxxxx”;

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");
$hdw_id = $_POST['hdw_id'];
$hdw_Country = $_POST['hdw_Country'];
$hdw_IP = $_POST['hdw_IP'];
$hdw_Referer = $_POST['hdw_Referer'];
$hdw_Browser = $_POST['hdw_Browser'];
$hdw_UserAgent = $_POST['hdw_UserAgent'];
$Position_Applying = $_POST['Position_Applying'];
$Position_one = $_POST['Position_one'];
$Position_two = $_POST['Position_two'];
$Position_three = $_POST['Position_three'];
$Position_type = $_POST['Position_type'];
$Shift_type = $_POST['Shift_type'];
$First_name =$_POST['First_name'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `new_app`(`hdw_id`, `hdw_Country`, `hdw_IP`, `hdw_Referer`, `hdw_ServerTime`, `hdw_Browser`, `hdw_UserAgent`, `Position_Applying`, `Position_one`, `Position_two`, `Position_three`, `Position_type`, `Shift_type`, `First_name`) 

 VALUES ('$hdw_id', '$hdw_Country', '$hdw_IP', '$hdw_Referer', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$hdw_Browser', '$hdw_UserAgent', '$Position_Applying', '$Position_one', '$Position_two', '$Position_three', '$Position_type', '$Shift_type', '$First_name') LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
    <table width="100%" height="508" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="20"     cellspacing="5">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" valign="middle">
            <h2>Thank you for your Application!</h2>
</p>

  </td></tr></tbody></table></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><?php include 'footer.php'; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @fixdreamer. I'm kind of a newbie and not sure where to put the items you mentioned. can you be more specific as to where I need to put them?

Comment: Also, @user5200287 I haven't a clue on how to convert this to mysqi ?? Any pointers or suggestions on where i could learn how to do it?

Comment: straight after your header(); commands add exit; before the } brackets or it will kill stop everything when it shouldn't. I think you have two of them. Mysqli requires you to change the connection file. I'd look at that when its all working correct as it won't be causing this problem.